# Indexnow protocol POST request with JSON on PYTHON

Tags: python, indexing, seo, bing

I am trying to make a POST request for [Indexnow protocol](https://www.indexnow.org/documentation), which allows the user to send link massive to search engine (BING) for instant indexing. As I read all documentation, I found that this protocol suggests such **JSON** request construction:

```
POST /indexnow HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: <searchengine>
{
  "host": "www.example.com",
  "key": "265f7fb3bd6c41118f6bf05568d9c825",
  "urlList": [
      "https://www.example.com/url1",
      "https://www.example.com/folder/url2",
      "https://www.example.com/url3"
      ]
}
```

I chose to use **Python**, and here is my code for this POST request:

```
import advertools as adv
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import time


def submit_url_set(set_:list, key, location, host="https://www.bing.com", headers={"Content-type":"application/json", "charset":"utf-8"}):
     key = "91ca7c564b334f38b0b1ed90eec8g8b2"
     data = {
     "host": "www.bing.com",
     "key": key,
     "keyLocation": "https://uchet.kz/91ca7c564b334f38b0b1ed90eec8g8b2.txt",
     "urlList": [
    'https://uchet.kz/news/formirovanie-obshchestva-chistogo-ot-korruptsii-dobivaetsya-tokaev/',
    'https://uchet.kz/news/pravila-polucheniya-iin-inostrantsu-v-rk-izmeneny/',
    'https://uchet.kz/news/zabolevaemost-koronavirusom-sredi-shkolnikov-vyrosla-v-13-raza/',
    'https://uchet.kz/news/izmeneny-pravila-provedeniya-tamozhennoy-ekspertizy/'
      ]
     }
     r = requests.post(host, data=data, headers=headers)
     return r.status_code
```

After script runs, nothing returns.
I expected the script to return server response code HTTP-code 200 OK

**What was I really expected**

*Getting the server response code for each indexing url*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of the code.

IndexNow API doesn't return a response, if you don't take an error message it means that the request has been taken.

You can check your log files to validate that.

Also, https://www.searchenginejournal.com/indexnow-api-python/429726/ in the article, this is stated.

Comment: I have read your article but your code did not fit my needs because it uses sitemap directory. Thank you for your answr

Comment: If you need to use all of the URLs from your website, try to use `adv.crawl("https://example.com", output_file="output.jl", follow_links=True`. It will crawl all websites, and you can extract the URLs the one that you want to index.

You can try this one: https://www.holisticseo.digital/python-seo/crawl-analyse-website/

Answer (score -1):

Go to the [Post Requests Online](https://reqbin.com/post-online)

1. Type your search engine URL
2. Put your code in the window below in this format:

   ```
   {
     "host": "your_site",
     "key": "your_key",
     "urlList": [
          "https://your_site/1",
          "https://your_site/2",
          "https://your_site/3"
         ]
    }
   ```
3. Press SEND.
4. Done

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hp4Z.png)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though, which is written in python...